# Turning a value[simp] example into a lemma. With functions in them

Tags: isabelle

assume I have a function

```
definition "foo_function x = x+1"
```

And I have some code which processes functions. For the sake of simplicity, let this code be the identity function `id`. I want to print an example. I want to print that

```
id foo_function = foo_function
```

The printing shall appear in the proof doc and I want it to be checked. How can I best achieve this?

I already tried a few things:

- `value ‹id foo_function›` raises `Wellsortedness error ...`
- `value[simp] ‹id foo_function›` returns `foo_function` in the output panel and is quite close to what I'm looking for. But I really want to print `id foo_function = foo_function` and have this checked. I don't want folks to go to the output panel.
- `lemma ‹id foo_function = foo_function› by eval` is what I'd like to have but it fails with `Wellsortedness error: Type 'a ⇒ 'a not of sort equal`
- `lemma ‹id foo_function = foo_function› by(code_simp)` fails with `Wellsortedness error: Type 'a ⇒ 'a not of sort equal`
- `lemma ‹id foo_function = foo_function› by(normalization)` fails with `Wellsortedness error: Type 'a ⇒ 'a not of sort equal`

I know that the underlying problem is equality of functions, which is absolutely not trivial and I don't expect `eval` to solve this. Yet, `value[simp] ‹id foo_function›` displays in the output panel exactly what I want to see, which gives me hope that there is a way to achieve what I'm looking for.

In my simplified example, `lemma ‹id foo_function = foo_function› by(simp add: foo_function_def)` would work. But for my real problem, there are way too many definitions which need unfolding to make this a pleasant choice. In particular, since I want to print a lot of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
ML‹
fun bar_conv ctxt =
  Conv.arg_conv (Conv.arg1_conv (Code_Simp.dynamic_conv ctxt) then_conv Conv.arg_conv (Code_Simp.dynamic_conv ctxt))

fun bar_tac ctxt =
  HEADGOAL (CONVERSION (bar_conv ctxt) THEN_ALL_NEW (resolve_tac ctxt @{thms refl}))
›

method_setup bar = ‹Scan.succeed (SIMPLE_METHOD o bar_tac)›

lemma ‹id foo_function = foo_function›
  by bar
```

What does it do?

- `bar_conv` defines a `conv` (which is a rewriting function) that rewrites both sides of the equation with `Code_Simp.dynamic_conv`, essentially the same thing that `code_simp` does, except for ignoring the equality sign. (The outher `arg_conv` is to dive into the `Trueprop` that every lemma has.)
- `bar_tac` turns the `conv` into a `tactic`, then applies the `refl` theorem, which discharges the remaining goal of the shape `x = x`.
- `method_setup` creates an Isar binding for the method.